# While using ajax post response coming in error block

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

While sending ajax post request, the data is going to service and while getting back from response it's going into above error function
can someone help me on this

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: serviceUrl,
    data: stringData,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "text", // the data type we want back, so text.  The data will come wrapped in xml
    success: function(response) {
        alert("successs :::::::::::::::" + $("#searchresultsA").html(data)); // show the string that was returned, this will be the data inside the xml wrapper
        return response;
    },
    error: function(response) {
        alert("error ::::::::::::" + response.responseText); // show the data inside the xml wrapper
        return response.responseText;
    },
    failure: function(response) {
        alert("failure ::::::::::::" + response);
        return response;
        }
   });
}
```

Comment: If the `error` handler is being hit it means that a non-successful HTTP code is being returned from the request. Check the console to see what the exact response and any error messages are

Comment: Also, don't use `alert()` for debugging as it coerces all data types to strings. Use `console.log()` or `console.dir()` instead

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `$http` over `$.ajax` with AngularJS. You are looking for a solution about why your AJAX response gives an error, whereas, [from you previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48880334/angularjs-https-post-returning-angular-js11706-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-h), it is clear that you need to know how to **parse** the data correctly.

Previously used `$http` (which is better than `$.ajax`) expects your data to arrive as **JSON**, but your *backend* sends it as a **plain text**, giving you a *JSON parser error*. You would need to specify how you are sending this information and whether it is encoded as JSON.

---

#### For PHP

There is a function `json_encode()` that you can use to return an object / array as JSON. Try the following code with your example:

```
echo json_encode( $json );
```

---

#### To verify your response

Consider checking what you are receiving from your backend with `console.log(response);` (*inside the asynchronous callback*). For example:

```
$http.post(url, stringData).
then((response)=>{
    console.log(response);
},(error)=>{
    console.log(error);
});
```